# How to check basic integer order relations in sympy?

Tags: numbers, integer, sympy

I have a (possibly relatively large) set of assumptions about multiple **integers** like `{x > -1, x < 5, x != 2, y > 0, x-2 < y}` and I would like to check whether certain other propositions like `{x > -5, x == 3, ...}` either true, false or could be both.

The docs say that explicit relationships like `Q.is_true(x < 3)` are not supported, so I tried using `.positive` property, but without any luck, e.g.

```
#    x > -1 => x > -3   - ?
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
with sympy.assuming(sympy.Q.positive(x+1), sympy.Q.integer(x)):
  print(sympy.ask(sympy.Q.positive(x+3)))
```

produces

`None`

Which means that the checker gave up on checking that.

Refine also does not seem to help much (probably uses assumptions anyway)

```
sympy.refine(x > 0, sympy.Q.is_true(x > -1))
```

If there's a different library that can check that, that also works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that python bindings for the [`z3`](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3#z3-bindings) solver best fitted for my problem. One can just download the binary release from the github page and add included folder into `$PYTHONPATH` , e.g.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${Z3FOLDER}/bin PYTHONPATH=${Z3FOLDER}/bin/python python
```

then these relations could be checked as

```
from z3 import *
x = Int('x')
s = Solver()
s.add(x > 10)
s.add(x > 12)
print(s)           // [x > 10, x > 12]
print(s.check())   // sat
print(s.model())   // [x = 13]
```